# how to add parameters to addTimeout function from deferred in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I have some problems in deferred.addTimeout. I want to pass some parameters to this function in the same way as pass parameters to the deferred.addCallback, but i can't.
May help come changes in Twisted library?
Help me please,
Luk

Comment: Pass parameters to what function?

Comment: Pass parameters to funtion called by deferred.addTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Use builtin [partials](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pass params into a function. I assume you're looking to pass in params [`onTimeoutCancel`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#addTimeout) function in [`Deferred.addTimeout`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#addTimeout)?

```
from functools import partial
from twisted.internet import defer, task

def callback_timeout(failure, timeout, **kw):
    print('params: {0}'.format(kw))

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    # use partials to set params in a function
    fn_timeout = partial(callback_timeout, a=1, b='B', c=12)
    # pass new partial function into addTimeout
    p = d.addTimeout(5, reactor, fn_timeout)
    yield d

task.react(main)
```

Comment: I like to pass message ID to function called by deferred.addTimeout for remove it from queue of sent messages

Comment: Yest, I'm looking to pass parameters to onTimeoutCancel Function